# Division algebra with finite center is finite

Tags: abstract-algebra

I asked this question: [Brauer group of a finite field is trivial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117318/brauer-group-of-a-finite-field-is-trivial) and then I accidentally logged out and I don't know how to log back on, so I had to create a new account.

So my question was: I know that finite skew fields are field, but how does it follow from this that the Brauer group of a finite field is trivial. As someone wrote, I see that it follows if the only division algebra with finite center is the finite center (field). So how do I see this fact? (being a bit slow here...)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn%27s_little_theorem

Comment: I have just merged the two accounts.

Comment: For reader reference: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/117318/22405